# RoboVM 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm, alljoyn

Im using libGDX to create a game. I have it all running fine on the android side but am having real difficulties in getting it to tun on iOS using RoboVM.
The issue is that im utilising a third party networking library (alljoyn).

I have tried referecing the .jar file and this makes the project compile but I end up with UnsatisfiedLink Exceptions.

I have also tried using the alljoyn static .a library but it ends up the same way.

Is it the case that robovm will only work with 3rd party libraries through the maintained bindings or am i missing a trick?

Answer (score 0):

I see [here](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/download) that there are different versions of the library for each platform.  That leads me to believe that this library depends on OS APIs, so you need to be using the iOS version of the library on iOS, not the Android or Windows versions. And if you use the iOS version, you will have to create a code binding from Objective-C to Java, as explained [here](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings#how-do-i-create-a-binding).

There is more info about robovm bindings [here](http://docs.robovm.com/advanced-topics/bro.html).